# NVidia or Radeon GPUs that support more than 4 active displays

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-radeon, mst

Are there any recent Nvidia or Radeon GPUs that support more than 4 active displays using one card? I've tried a few that have 5 ports but they usually only allow 3 or 4 active displays at one time. On Linux this is easy to detect using the `xrandr --listproviders` command, which for my GeForce FTX 970 shows **crtcs: 4** meaning it only allows 4 active displays.

```
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x4, Source Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 8 associated providers: 1 name:nouveau
```

Which GPUs allow more than 4 displays when using DisplayPort Multi Stream Transport (MST) or other methods of splitting a single port into multiple active displays? All of the Nvidia GPUs that I've checked look like they only support 4 active displays even if they have 5 or 6 different ports.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a footnote on the (now dated) [AMD FirePro w7100](https://www.amd.com/documents/firepro-w7100-data-sheet.pdf) data sheet stating:

> Three 4K displays at 60Hz requires displays with DisplayPort 1.2 interfaces with support for HBR2 ( for SST ) or HBR2 with MST. Four 4K displays at 30Hz requires displays with at least one
>   DisplayPort interface. Four 4K displays at 30Hz with HDMI 1.4a interface can also be supported via DisplayPort to HDMI adapters that support HDMI 4K output. **Six full-HD displays** requires DP 1.2 MST hub or at least two monitors capable of DP 1.2 daisy-chaining.

Meaning when using MST you could get up to 6 active displays. I checked the data sheet for the newer AMD Radeon [Pro WX 5100](https://www.amd.com/Documents/radeon-pro-wx5100-datasheet.pdf) and [Pro WX 7100](https://www.amd.com/Documents/radeon-pro-wx7100-datasheet.pdf) which state:

```
Display Output Support (@ 60Hz)
4 @ 1920x1080
4 @ 3840x2160
2 @ 5120x2880
1 @ 7680x4320
```

But they don't state anything about how many total active displays are supported when using MST. I ended up buying the AMD Radeon Pro WX 5100 and can confirm it supports up to 6 active display engines when two of the inputs use Display Port MST:

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x5d cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 8 associated providers: 0 name:AMD Radeon (TM) Pro WX 5100 Graphics @ pci:0000:01:00.0
```

The Radeon Pro WX Series Quick Start Guide (which I cannot find an online copy of) also includes more details about the supported display configurations:

[image: AMD Radeon Pro WX Display Configurations 6 total]

Comment: Note you may also need to force 60Hz refresh rate. A kernel update recently added 120/150Hz modes, which didn't work with my previous 6 display setup https://twitter.com/GBrayUT/status/1246959345385926657